# Fading pixels[] will not completely fade black (with bitshifting algorithm). How can I make it completely?

Tags: processing, transparency, fade, alpha, pixel

I want to copy faded pixels from pixels[] to f.pixels[] (of my PGraphics object) and then draw the f image back onto the display. Doing this over and over in draw() is intended to fade the white rectangle to black to match the background, but it is not fading all the way.

It is fading smoothly a little bit, but then it stops fading at some grey color. The lower the fade_amount, the less it ultimately fades.

How can I get the white square to fade all the way to black? Why is it not doing that with this code?

Thanks!

P.S. I have the Pgraphics f object there because I want an off screen drawing buffer later in this project so I can create a feedback loop including transformations during the copying to make something like when you point a camera showing on a tv into the tv.

Also, this is written in processing 1.5.1, it's the latest version that works on my computer.

```java
PGraphics f;
int win_size = 1000;

void setup(){
  size(win_size, win_size);
  f = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);
  background(0,0,0);
  stroke(255,255);
  rect((win_size/2) -40, (win_size/2) -40, 80, 80);
}

void draw(){
  fade_and_copy_pixels(f); //fades window pixels and then copies pixels to f
  background(0,0,0);
  image(f,0,0);
}

void fade_and_copy_pixels(PGraphics f){
  loadPixels();  //load windows pixels
  f.loadPixels(); //loads 2nd layer pixels

  // Loop through every pixel in window
  for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
      color p = pixels[i];
      // get alpha value
      int a = (p >> 24) & 0xFF ;
      // reduce alpha value
      int fade_amount = 5;//at 2 it fades about half way to black, the higher the fadeamount the more it fades. weird
      a = max(0, a-fade_amount); 
      // assign color with new alpha-value
      p = (a<<24 | p & 0xFFFFFF) ;
      f.pixels[i] = p;
  }
  updatePixels(); //dont need because I am not wanting to directly edit pixels[]
  f.updatePixels(); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Processing \`fill()\` with alpha never completely fill?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317685/why-does-the-processing-fill-with-alpha-never-completely-fill)

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but why don't the latest versions of Processing work on your computer? Processing 1.5 is very old at this point.

Comment: I am using OSX 10.8.2 on a Hackintosh I built... so that might have something to do with it. I forget the exact reasons or if I even figured out why. I vaguely remember that last time I tried getting the latest versions of Java running with this OS I could not get much working. I have Java 6 and that is the only java that seems to work, so I believe the newer Processing versions don't work without a higher jre or jdk. 

Basically I think it is because I am using an old version of processing.

Why do you ask?

Comment: I asked because Processing 1.5 is very old at this point. Using Java 6 is not just a security risk, but it's also going to give you a bunch of headaches when you try to work with libraries and whatnot.